Could anyone help me write this quote in Korean Vertically?
I was wondering if anyone could help me with this writing in Korean. This quote “우리 함께면 세계는 아름다워” is a song lyric I want to get on a tapestry as well as a tattoo down my forearm. It is written out horizontally. How would you write this vertically and/or is there a way to write it in one straight line going down?

Vertical writing means writing letters from top to bottom.  For multi-line writing, you can write it from left-to-right or right-to-left, though right-to-left is the more common direction.
Multi-line example:
세   우
계   리
는   
　   함
아   께
름   면
다
워


There's nothing special about vertical writing.  You just write the words vertically in the same order and with the same spacing.  I'll show a single line and a two line case below.
우
리
함
께
면
세
계
는
아
름
다
워

우　   세
리　   계
 　 는
함
께　   아
면　   름
 　 다
 　 워
